# Item generator controlled by probability

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, probability

I'm pretty new to JS but I want to make a very basic RPG item generator that is controlled by probability. This is what I have come up with.

I have a problem with the itemtype part. After the probability roll is done for itemtype, I want to randomly generate a group of elements under weapons, accessories, and armors.

It should be something like Rare Sword, Uncommon staff, Common gloves, or Common Chest.

How do I go about this?

```
var rarityNum = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 100 );
var itemNum = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 100 );

var rarity;
if ( rarityNum > 75 ) { rarity = "rare "; }
else if ( rarityNum > 65 ) { rarity = "uncommon "; }
else { rarity = "common "; }

var weapons =["sword","bow","staff"];
var armors =["chest","leggings","gloves"];

var itemtype;
if ( itemNum > 51 ) { itemtype = "weapons"; }
else if ( itemNum > 40 ) { itemtype = "accessories"; }
else { itemtype = "armors"; }

document.write (rarity);
document.write (itemtype);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var item = {
  "Weapon" : ["Sword", "Bow"],
  "Armor"  : ["Chest", "Leggings", "Gloves", "Helmet"],
  "Access" : ["Ring", "Bracelet", "Amulet"]
};

var rareness   = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 100 )
  , item_type  = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 100 )
;//randoms

var rarity =
    rareness > 75? "Rare"     :
    rareness > 65? "Uncommon" :
                   "Common"   ;

var type =
    item_type > 51? "Weapon" :
    item_type > 40? "Access" :
                    "Armor"  ;

var item_list  = item[type]
  , item_index = Math.round( Math.random() * (item_list.length - 1) )
;//items

document.write( rarity + " " + item_list[item_index] );
```

Comment: But what if weapon had a different array length than armor?

Comment: I've updated the code to show you what to do with variable length item lists ;-)